# error while calling a java Method

Tags: java

I am learning java. I am getting a lot of errors when I try to keep the methods, which I am trying to invoke, inside the main method.

I am trying to declare a couple of variables x,y. However, I want to invoke the math operations when specific methods are called, such as addMethod, subtractMethod, so on.

When I try to include the methods within the public method, I am getting an error.

```
 package exampleclass;

public class MathLearning {
    //declaring variables
    static int x = 9;
    static int y = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int resu=0;
        additMethod(resu);
        subtMethod(resu);
        multMethod(resu);
        divMethod(resu);    

    private static void divMethod(int resu) {
        resu = x+y;
        System.out.println(resu);

    }

    private static void multMethod(int resu) {
        resu = x-y;
        System.out.println(resu);

    }

    private static void subtMethod(int resu) {
        resu = x*y;
        System.out.println(resu);

    }

    private static void additMethod(int resu) {
        resu = x/y;
        System.out.println(resu);

    }

    }
}
```

When I keep the methods outside the main method, I do not get an error.

```
    package exampleclass;

public class MathLearning {
    //declaring variables
    static int x = 9;
    static int y = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int resu=0;
        additMethod(resu);
        subtMethod(resu);
        multMethod(resu);
        divMethod(resu);


    }

    private static void divMethod(int resu) {
        resu = x+y;
        System.out.println(resu);

    }

    private static void multMethod(int resu) {
        resu = x-y;
        System.out.println(resu);

    }

    private static void subtMethod(int resu) {
        resu = x*y;
        System.out.println(resu);

    }

    private static void additMethod(int resu) {
        resu = x/y;
        System.out.println(resu);

    }


}
```

Comment: You can't have methods inside methods.

Comment: For future reference, you could have easily figured this out by searching google for `why can't I put a method inside another method java`. You will save a **lot** of time in the future if you learn how to ask good questions on google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I try to include the methods within the public method, I am getting an error.

You cannot have nested methods in Java<sup>1</sup>. Indeed, your second snippet has the methods in an appropriate location; outside of `main`.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Aside) Well, I guess you *technically can* since you can declare classes within methods, meaning you can ultimately declare a method within another method:

```
void foo1() {
    class X {
        void foo2() {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You should very rarely have to do something like that, though.

Comment: +1 I would be very suprise to see a real use case for this kind of situations

Answer (score 2):

In java, you cannot declare methods inside other methods (like you can, e.g., in [python](/questions/tagged/python)). Methods are defined under classes, like you do in your second code example.